# Removing the reference through the loop

Tags: mongodb

Field 'attributeMetaDataList' has reference like

```
, "path" : "Health & Personal Care > Health > Health Aids > Bathroom Aids & Safety > Bathtub Rails", "attributeMetaDataList" : [    {
        "$ref" : "AttributeMetadata",
        "$id" : ObjectId("50726bd4e4b0adf08145e4f1")
    },  {
        "$ref" : "AttributeMetadata",
        "$id" : ObjectId("50726bd4e4b0adf08145e4f2")
    },  {
        "$ref" : "AttributeMetadata",
        "$id" : ObjectId("50726bd4e4b0adf08145e4f3")
    },  {
        "$ref" : "AttributeMetadata",
        "$id" : ObjectId("50726bd4e4b0adf08145e4f4")
    },  {
        "$ref" : "AttributeMetadata",
        "$id" : ObjectId("50726bd4e4b0adf08145e4f5")
    } ]
```

i want to remove this reference through the loop.

I have used,

```
db.Category.find({"path": /Health & Personal Care/}).forEach(function(x){
  x.attributeMetaDataList=$unset
 }
)
```

this is not working for me. Any Help?

Comment: `db.Category.update({"path": /Health & Personal Care/}, {$unset: {attributeMetaDataList: 1}})` Assuming that `attributeMetaDataList` is the field that holds this reference that is

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example of the doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Category.find({"path":/^Health/}).forEach(function(x){
  db.Category.update({_id:x._id},{$unset:{"attributeMetaDataList":1}})
})
```

its worked for me.